# Angular Test: Which Line Error Number failed

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular11

How do I get which line number failed in Angular unit test? Right now it says error below, and I have to look through code to find actual Line number. It could be in multiple places.

If no one knows, this should be a new Angular feature request.

```
6) ngOnInit should initializeNewBatchForm
     TaxExtensionComponent
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_we
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please share a complete stacktrace of the error as text instead of an image?

Also, I believe there's some code in your `ngOnInit` where you're trying to read the `value` property on some object. But your test hasn't initialized that property yet. And hence the error.

Comment: yeah, I just updated the code

Comment: I think that SiddAjmera was asking for ngOnInit source code.